# phpmailer sends email but does not include attachment

Tags: phpmailer

I have the following code to send an email via  phpmailer, it works fine if I don't include the AddAttachment line so know that all other constants and variables translate OK.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = EW_SMTP_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->Username = EW_SMTP_SERVER_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = EW_SMTP_SERVER_PASSWORD;
$mail->From = EW_SENDER_EMAIL;
$mail->FromName = EW_SENDER_EMAIL;
$mail->Subject = $mail_subject;
$mail->Body = $mail_message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->AddAttachment($mail_attachment);
$mail->AddAddress("something@yahoo.co.uk");
$mail->Send();
```

If I include the attachment line then the email is sent without the attachment and does not give any error message.

If I echo $mail_attachment it gives me
'leaflets/Booklet.pdf', 'leaflets/timetable-12.pdf'

My script runs in a folder called 'iytinfo' and the 'leaflets' folder is inside this one. The 2 files definately exist in the 'leaflets' folder - have I specified the path incorrectly or is there something else I am missing?

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add multiple files with one call to `AddAttachment`. You have to make two calls like this:

```
// ... 
$mail->AddAttachment('leaflets/Booklet.pdf');
$mail->AddAttachment('leaflets/timetable-12.pdf');
// ...
```

Or you loop through an array of your file names or whatever.

Comment: Thankyou attachments are now included.  Have seen numberous examples online which suggest multiple attachments can be sent with one call in a comma separated string which is why I attempted it.  If I needed to add multiple addresses in the AddAddress or BCC should that also be done in the same way with more than one call?

Comment: No. Email-Addresses separated with commas are no problem.

Comment: Your help appreciated.  Thankyou